# Drawing markers on map using data retrieved from my database

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I was trying to find a solution on api guides and here as well but I've failed to find one. What I am trying to do is to use data stored in my database to draw markers on google map (api v3). 
Here's how I get data from my DB:

```
function getDevs(){

    $query = " SELECT id, lat, lon, login, id_devtask FROM dev WHERE online='1'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $onlineDevs = array();
    $singledev = array();

    while($dev=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $singledev['id']=$dev['id'];
        $singledev['lat']=$dev['lat'];
        $singledev['lon']=$dev['lon'];
        $singledev['login']=$dev['login'];
        $singledev['id_devtask']=$dev['id_devtask'];
        $onlineDevs[]=$singledev;
    }       
    return $onlineDevs;
}
```

Then I do     $somerandomarray=getDevs(); on page that I need this data. It appears to work properly, I get all the wanted data. But now I have no clue how to use all the lats, lons, and logins (it's a name) to draw markers on my map. Here's my map (code taken from google's api guide):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title:"Hello World!"
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Have you got any idea how to do that? (By the way, in future I will need to get data from a marker (probably just id) to make some post to database. )

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $somerandomarray holds your db result then try this

```
var jsonStr = '<?php echo json_encode($somerandomarray) ?>';
    var LatLong = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatlng
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = [];

        for(var i=0;i<LatLong.length;i++){

           var LatLong1 = new google.maps.LatLng(LatLong[i].lat, LatLong[i].lon);
           marker.push(new google.maps.Marker({position: LatLong1, map: map}));

       }
    }
```

Comment: I copied whole code and changed var names to match my own etc. It doesn't work. But nevermind, I'd like to ask what does: <?php foreach($somerandomarray as $arr) {?> mean?
It looks weird to me, same as
<?php } ?>

Comment: This is your result array from php as you said in your example `Then I do $somerandomarray=getDevs(); on page that I need this data`

Comment: But I don't get it, why do you use " { " right after that loop, and why it ends with <?php } ?>

Comment: Okay, this worked for me:
    var marker = [];
  foreach($arajka as $a){
   echo "var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(" .$a['lat'] .",".$a['lon'].");"; 
   echo "marker.push(new google.maps.Marker({position: LatLng, map: map}));";
   
  }

Thanks for your marker.push and time:)

Comment: But its not the good way. i will update the post with a better solution.

Comment: It's kinda spaghetti but for now it's working, but if you got anything better, I'll be glad to see that! :)

Comment: By the way, do you know if I can push "title" together with LatLng? I got it stored in my ['login'] field. I tried to make new variable by echo "var t =".$a['login'].";"; then in push I tried to add "title: t" but it didn't work. Now I'm gonna try ur current code.

Comment: About your edited code: it works fine I guess. +it seems to be more elegant code, thanks a lot!:) If you had any ideas about adding a title to it, please let me know. Thanks again!
Well, works now, I had a typo...

Comment: you can add infowindow to a marker specify var infowindow = [];  `infoWindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: 'your title',
    });` and then attach each marker with infowindow